# How to I read the text on this page? (See body)

Tags: installing

I don't know anything about Latex, Mathjax, or Github, aside from the fact that they exist and somehow combine to prevent from from seeing what I need to on this page: https://github.com/psibi/how-to-prove/blob/master/chapter%203/section3.2.tex. What do I need to do to be able to read this clearly?

Comment: Hm, compile it?

Comment: it is unrelated to mathjax, and github isn't related other than the file happens to be on that web site, you need to download it from the site then pass it as input to the latex program which you need to download separately, or use a free online latex service such as sharelatex

Comment: For me personally, this is easier to read, because i keep forgetting the mathematic symbol language of *in* and *notin* and the like.

Comment: If you only need *this single file* as pdf, a user here might send you the pdf. No need to know anything about LaTeX and friends, or Github. If you need this more than once, you better read a bit about the basics of git and LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

you can compile it quite easily using [this tool](http://latex.aslushnikov.com).

Another options is to copy the text and paste it into sharelatex, overleaf, or any other latex editor and compile

Comment: ... and you get [This document](http://latex.aslushnikov.com/compile?url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fpsibi%2Fhow-to-prove%2Fmaster%2Fchapter%25203%2Fsection3.2.tex)...